# OC 3.9.0 + Istio

Tags: docker, openshift, istio

I would llike to try Istio on Openshift platform. Could somebody confirm if succesfully install Istio locally on Openshift on Windows 10 machine? 
I am not able to run the newest Openshift (oc 3.11 or oc 3.10) because of error

```
 error: cannot create volume share
```

And I can't run Istio on Openshift 3.9 because some Istio components won't start. Also on official page only Openshift version 3.10+ is mentioned. 
Is it worth to try Istio with Openshift 3.9 ?

Comment: I had tried to install istio 1.0.2 on OpenShift 3.9. All Istio components were in running status while mixer was not working.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, I think Istio is not stable to be Enterprise Ready, so Red Hat does not make it in its official supported list.
If you want just give a try with this, I highly recommend you to take a look at this https://learn.openshift.com/servicemesh/ to avoid the boring installation things.